# How to avoid overwriting existing files while using tar command?

Tags: bash, tar, data-recovery

The **tar** command just overwrote my file an hour ago while I was trying to make a tar to backup it.

I ran

```
tar zcvf foo.tex foo.bib
```

and after that my tex source file lost. What's worse, this is the second time I lost my file in this way.

I use gvim, but 'u' command can recover my file. After browsing some help entries about 'backup', 'undofile', I just can not find a way to avoid tar command from overwriting my file again.

Then I try to find a parameter like '-i' from **cp** or **mv**, but among the many parameters of **tar** I can't find one.

I wonder how can I avoid this kind of things happening again, for I am a little unconfident about remembering to add the new foo.tar thing that I always forget next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your `.bash_login` file.  `alias tar=tar --backup=simple`  This will append a ~ to the file it is about to overwrite.

So when you create the archive it will always run

```
tar --backup=simple zcvf foo.tex foo.bib
```

and after execution a foo.tex~ will exist (this is the actual tex file and the archive will be in at foo.tex)

Comment: Thanks,this is exactly the answer that I need.(Why didn't I discover the --backup option when searching the man page...). _Another question_ :what does the **CONTROL** in the man page mean,what are some other **CONTROL** options except 'simple' in your answer?

Comment: @bigeast instead of simple, the alternative is number iirc.

Comment: @sparticvs I tried "tar --backup=simple" in my Terminal (bash) and got the error "tar: Option --backup=simple is not supported". What is "number iirc"? (Noob level here. Just started learning using shells).

Comment: @bigeast I couldn't find it in the man pages either.

Comment: @politicus iirc = if i remember correctly. Another alternative to `tar --backup=simple` is `tar --backup=numbered` which will number the backups sequentially.

Comment: Instead of an alias, you could export VERSION_CONTROL.

Answer (score 1):

Use output redirection instead of specifying a file name. This applies to many commands, not just tar.

Of course you have `set -o noclobber` (also spelled `set -C`) in your `.bashrc`, right?

```
$ tar zc >foo.tex foo.bib
bash: foo.tex: cannot overwrite existing file
```

If you often issue this command, don't type it manually: write a [makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29).

```
foo.tar.gz: foo.tex foo.bib
        tar czf $@ $^
```

Use tarballs only when you need to send them to someone else, not to make backups. Instead of making backups of old versions, use [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) (CVS, Mercurial, Git, etc., whatever floats your boat). (Do back up the repository in case your disk fails or you accidentally mangle or erase the repository.)

Comment: I haven't heard of 'noclobber' option before,but now I find it's useful.And thank you for your other advices.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because 'short' options for tar allow you to combine things in a way that obfuscates that the `foo.tex` belongs to the `f` option.

The full version of your command (with a modern version of `tar`) would be:

```
tar --create --file foo.tex --gzip --verbose foo.big
```

or with shortened options:

```
tar -c -f foo.tex -z -v foo.big
```

Both these are, in my experience, way more obviously incorrectly writing to a file `foo.tex`.

If you would do:

```
tar --create --file --gzip --verbose foo.tex foo.big
```

You get a file `--gzip`, and this is something I hope you do not regularly use as a filename, so that overwriting is not a problem. (BTW you can remove a file with such a filename with `rm -- --gzip`.)

The one character options for `tar` without `-` are an older/original way to specify options.  Unix dinosaurs, like me, tend to use them, but I think they are confusing. I recommend using the fuller 'dashed' versions seperately until you feel more confident using `tar`.

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer the behaviour of `7z` (7-Zip).  I couldn't get it to overwrite an existing file when compressing.  It supports tar output (`-t tar`).

There's also atool - I tried it and the UI looks nice:

```
apack a b
apack: a: format not known, identifying using file
apack: a: format is `tar'
apack: a: refusing to overwrite existing file
```

Answer (score 0):

First it is quite easy to remember the right characters:

- `czf` = create zipped file
- `xzf` = extract zipped file

If you think this way you should always get it right.

The other thing with important data is, having it in some version control. I recommend `git` for that. It will save you all your history locally and allows you to push all of it to any other medium. - Very handy and no more backups using tar.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are giving the same file name as your source to the tar ball.

if the source file is `foo.tex`, that needs to be archived then you should do the following:

```
tar zcvf foo.tgz foo.tex
```

if there are mulitple files then do the following

```
 tar zcvf foo.tgz foo.tex foo.bib
```

if you are trying to do the incremental tar ball then use this [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Incremental-Dumps.html). I have not tried it yet but I think it is best to use git if you are trying to do version control.

Comment: That's why I my tex source file is overwritten by the gziped file of the later bib file.